# C++ 20 Modules: Submodul vs ModulPartition diffrence

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to learn the concept of modules that come with the C++20 feature. The concept of SubModule and ModulePartition confuses me a lot. They basically both do the same job, but I couldn't decide which one to use when and under what conditions.

Can you explain the difference to me exactly?

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-divide-modules

Comment: Lose the last sentence. It transforms the question from good (but could use a bit more description of the research you've performed) to Needs focus (more than one question in a single question) and Opinion-based (because you can never get everyone to agree on what best practices really are).

Comment: @user4581301 So can you explain the difference to me? I'm a very obsessive person, I've been trying to understand the difference for three days. I'm a real idiot

Comment: No I can't, unfortunately. Haven't gotten to modules or concepts yet. Still trying to completely wrap my head around the changes to strict aliasing.

Comment: I guess the key part is: *"The division of modules into modules and submodules is a means for the module designer to give the user of the module the possibility to more granular import parts of the module. This observation does not apply to module partitions."* Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-named-modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#:~:text=Module%20partitions%20are%20meant%20to,zero%20or%20more%20implementation%20files.

Comment: “Submodules” aren’t a thing; that’s just an organizational idiom for packaging related modules into one convenience module.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between a "submodule" and a module partition is simple:

Submodules *do not exist* as a part of the module system. Module partitions are part of the module system.

A module partition is a component of a module which can be imported by other files that are themselves components of a module. This allows them to be used for private declarations that are used by multiple module implementation units, or for splitting a large module's interface into different files so that your single primary module interface unit isn't gigantic.

Partitions are effectively a way of namespace scoping a module. The partition `X:Y` can only ever be accessed by module units that are part of module `X`. The primary module interface of `X` may indeed `export import` a partition, but the outside world has no idea that those declarations are in the purview of a partition of `X`.

Within a module unit for the module `X`, you can import a partition `Y` of that module by naming it with `:Y`. That is, because the only partitions that a module unit for `X` has access to are the partitions of `X`, so there's no need to repeat yourself.

A "submodule" is not a part of a module system; it is a way of thinking about and treating a particular module. By convention, people use the naming convention `X.Y` to say that `Y` is a conceptual "submodule" of `X`. But this purely a convention; it has no *syntactic* legitimacy. That is, the *language* has no idea that the module `X.Y` has any inherent relationship to `X` (`X` could `export import X.Y;`, but there's no requirement to do so).

A module that is treated as a submodule is still, as far as the language is concerned, a full-fledged module with all of the powers and restrictions thereof. Its name has no special meaning, and you cannot make such a module "private" in any meaningful capacity.

Submodules (aka: just another module) does not "do the same job" as a proper partition at all. Submodules are exactly as visible to the outside world as the module that they are conceptually a "submodule" of.

The primary point of a module partition is that they are *implementation details* of a module. They're not something that leaks out into the module's interface. Submodules do. And maybe that's what you want.

But remember this: unlike headers, the cost of including a module is not based on how much stuff is in that module. So there isn't much point to breaking your library's interface into a bunch of tiny submodules(which is probably why the C++ committee is going to toss the entire standard library into a single `std` module instead of dozens of smaller modules). It's useful to have the interface defined in multiple files, but the outside world doesn't have to *see* them. How you choose to organize your code should be about your convenience, not how the user interacts with it.

Hence module partitions.

If what you want to do is provide multiple components of your library as different importable units, submodules are the tool for doing that. But if you're just organizing your code within a module and external code shouldn't need to know about that organization, that's what partitions are for.

Comment: I saw a simpler explanation for "submodules" - they aren't submodules, they are kinda modules with "hierarchy-suggesting names". Unfortunately your explanation doesn't enumerate a single thing a partition can do that "integrated modules" cannot. Say, I have `std.thread.mutex`, `std.thread.cv` and `std.thread.thread` and then `std.thread` that export-imports all those above. Importing subparts as private are also possible this way. How are partitions here any better, or what features can they provide towards this?

Comment: @Ethouris: As pointed to earlier, partitions have two advantages: namespace hiding (partition names can never collide with other modules. Someone else theoretically could name their module `std.thread`) and access to non-`exproted` entities defined elsewhere in the module. You cannot privately import a regular module; if your module can import a module, then *anyone* can so long as they know the name. It is "private" only by convention. It is therefore no different from a detail namespace.

Comment: How does that work exactly? So far I thought that in order to import a partition inside a module, you simply use `import`, and as such you can still only use those things that this partition exposes as an interface. Unless there's some method to "import" a partition that is only available for a master module and inaccessible for an unrelated module or application. Or that if you import a partition in the master module, you have access to everything that is defined in the partition file.

Comment: @Ethouris: There's no such thing as a "master module". A module unit (a file that defines some portion of a module) can import other modules outside of that module, and it can import module partitions of the same module via `import :partition_name` syntax. If a module unit imports a partition, then it has access to all declarations defined in that partition, whether they are `export`ed or not.

Comment: Ah, now you're talking. So, of course there exists a "master module" (for a partition) that is the only module where you can specify the import as `import :partition_name` instead of `import module_name:partition_name` if `module_name` is the module itself. And this specifies "importing" (that is, allows access) of both the public and private parts of that partition.

Comment: @Ethouris: "*So, of course there exists a "master module" (for a partition)*" There is no such thing. *Any* module unit of the module `M` can import any partition within the module `M` (so long as the usual rules about circular references are held up). There is no "master module". It's a directed-acyclic graph, not a tree. Also, *no module* can do `import module_name:partition_name`. You either `import module_name` or you `import :partition_name` of your module. That's it.

Comment: @Ethouris one difference between partitions and "submodule" is that when importing a fellow partition, unexported functions are also imported, whereas in case of submodule only exported functions are imported.